# How to read a csv file by refering to variables in R

Tags: r, csv

Now I have file in the folders like:

"marketing.csv"

"HR.csv"

"ITbudget.csv"

......

I want to write a a function so that I can enter the name of the file, and R programme will read the corresponding .csv files. I tried to write it as follows:

```
function readfiles (filenames) {
  i <- paste(trimws(filenames),".csv")
  inputfile <- read.csv(i)
  ...........}
```

However, when I print out the result of i, it shows:

```
"Marketing .csv"
```

Which one more space is inculded, and cannot be deleted by trimws () Function. 
How can I solve this problem? Or is there better way to read the file?
Many thanks for your help in advance =)

Comment: `paste0(filenames,".csv")` or `paste(filenames,".csv", sep="")`. Or just get the filenames programmatically. If the csv files are in your current working directory: `filenames = list.files(pattern="csv$")`. To read all the files into a list of data frames: `df.list = lapply(filenames, read.csv)`.

Comment: `function readfiles (filenames) { ... }`?  That is not correct syntax.  I think you meant `readfiles <- function(filenames) { ... }` maybe?

Comment: ＠Rich Scriven　You are right, my typo =D

Comment: @eipi10 The function Paste0 works! Thanks!

Comment: Close on basis of just a typo. (Although could have been a downvote for failing to read the manual.)